# Prove there exists a sequence of bounded numbers $(v_1,v_2,..)$ such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nv_n = f(x)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $(X,\|\cdot\|)=(l^1,\|\cdot\|_1)$ and let $f$ be a bounded linear functional. Prove there exists a bounded sequence $(v_1,v_2,...)$ of real numbers  such that:
$$f(x)=f((a_1,a_2,a_3,..))=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_nv_n$$ for all $x=(a_1,a_2,...)\in l^1$

I cannot tell if I am being dopey but surely just the bounded sequence (1,1,1,1,...) works? This question is worth 6 marks though and therefore can someone outline what it is i'm trying to prove exactly?

Comment: There are infinitely many different possibilities for what $f$ is, and if you choose $(1,1,1,1,\ldots)$ you are determining $f$ to be one specific thing.  Notice that $v_k$ should equal $f((0,0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots))$, and try to prove that this sequence works.  (It is a standard textbook result, part of showing that $(\ell^1)^*\cong \ell^\infty$.)

Comment: Ok so how should I begin to tackle this?